# Regular expression that would allow numbers from 1-9 excluding 0 and alphabets

Tags: integer, expression

I am looking for regular expression that would allow only positive integers(1-9)excluding 0 and alphabets.
It can accept 01, 10 , 201 .
It should not accept 0 , 00, 000....
I had tried most of the regular expressions available on google.
But nothing worked.
Pls help.

Comment: I tried using ^(?=\d*[1-9])\d+$
But this allows 0 , 01, 10 , 201 as well. All i need is it should not accept 0 but accept 01,10,201

Comment: check the answer might help

Answer (score 0):

0*(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*

Comment: You need to take the spaces out for this to work, but otherwise it's ok.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The expression that you had provided accepts 0 .

Comment: @rahda I provided nuffin' and 01, 002, 0005678989 are apparently okay.

Comment: Poor me is not allowed to comment other posts, but alands answer does not allow something like 001, which should be allowed if I understood the question.

Comment: @Kackao Yes you are right .. It should allow 001 but not 0

Comment: This is correct, but you should use character classes `[1-9]` and `[0-9]` instead of long (1|2|...) sequences

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplified like

```
0?[1-9][0-9]+
```

Check out http://regexpal.com it's online regex - can save a lot of time debugging

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`[1-9][0-9]+`

It will Exclude `0`

Comment: The expression allows 0, but doesnt accept 0.0 , .0     
Ideally I am looking for one that excludes 0 as well

Comment: It should exclude 0 as well

Comment: It doesnt. Accepts 0 as well

Comment: @radha anyspecific requirment other than that?
updated

Comment: As i said earlier, it should not accept 0 , decimals, alphabets . The expression that you had provided work fine but it doesnt work only for 0 .

Comment: append the other regex to it